# Anyone know how to write in a short way the folowing code

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, types

I'm trying to change the type of many columns or range of them, I need to know if exist a easy way to do, I am right?

```
In:
 for col in list(df.columns[2:8]):
    df=df.astype({col:'category'})
 df.dtypes

Out:
VAERS_ID         int64
VAX_TYPE        object
VAX_NAME      category
SYMPTOM1      category
SYMPTOM2      category
SYMPTOM3      category
SYMPTOM4      category
SYMPTOM5      category
RECVDATE        object
ALLERGIES       object
```

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 2:8] = df.iloc[:, 2:8].astype('category')`

Comment: Thanks Henry for remember me, I forgot the iloc function I started using df.columns[]
 but I got errors. I didn't try with iloc LOL